# Css div margin and center

Tags: html, css

I want to center everything on my code but I tried a few things and it's stills remains on the left side, so I know that is coming from `float:left`

About `cizgi` style when I  don't put `float:left` they looks overlap instead being separated.

`cizgi` color must be white but I made it black for showing it easier.

It must looks like this:
[image: D]

**My Code:**

```css
.cizgi {
  min-height: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  float: left;
}
.social {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  float: left;
}
.twitter {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Tdon7vV.png') no-repeat 0 -2px;
  width: 43px;
  height: 43px;
  float: left;
}
.facebook {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Tdon7vV.png') no-repeat -55px -2px;
  width: 43px;
  height: 44px;
  float: left;
}
.instagram {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Tdon7vV.png') no-repeat -105px 0;
  width: 46px;
  height: 45px;
  float: left;
}
.pinter {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Tdon7vV.png') no-repeat -160px 0;
  width: 43px;
  height: 44px;
  float: left;
}
.posta {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Tdon7vV.png') no-repeat -212px -1px;
  width: 43px;
  height: 43px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="cizgi"></div>
<div class="social">
  <div class="twitter"></div>
  <div class="facebook"></div>
  <div class="instagram"></div>
  <div class="pinter"></div>
  <div class="posta"></div>
</div>
<div class="cizgi"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To center:

- Remove `float:left` from `.social` and reduce the `width` from `600px` to its maximum `width` that will have : `220px`

#### To have the background with those borders:

- Add a parent class (I named `bg`) give it `background color` and `padding`
- change your social items from `float:left` to `display:inline-block`
- add `margin` top/bottom to your `.cizgi`

```css
.bg {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 5px 0
}
.cizgi {
  min-height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
.social {
  width: 220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0
}
.social > div {
  display: inline-block
}
.twitter {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Tdon7vV.png') no-repeat 0 -2px;
  width: 43px;
  height: 43px;
}
.facebook {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Tdon7vV.png') no-repeat -55px -2px;
  width: 43px;
  height: 44px;
}
.instagram {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Tdon7vV.png') no-repeat -105px 0;
  width: 46px;
  height: 45px;
}
.pinter {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Tdon7vV.png') no-repeat -160px 0;
  width: 43px;
  height: 44px;
}
.posta {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Tdon7vV.png') no-repeat -212px -1px;
  width: 43px;
  height: 43px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="cizgi"></div>
  <div class="social">
    <div class="twitter"></div>
    <div class="facebook"></div>
    <div class="instagram"></div>
    <div class="pinter"></div>
    <div class="posta"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cizgi"></div>
</div>
```